# Java regular expression to get characters between double quotes

Tags: java, regex

I need to figure out a regular expression (Pattern) to be able to get characters between double quotes.

It's a little hard to explain, but here is what I want:

If I run this through said expression:

```
say("ex" + "ex2", "ex3");
```

I will then be able to get three matches, which are;

```
"ex", "ex2", and "ex3"
```

all in their own strings.

I've already tried this expression:

```
Pattern.compile("\\\"(.*)\\\"");
```

But instead of giving me three different `.group()`s, I get one `.group` which is `"ex", "ex2", and "ex3"`

So does anyone know an expression to give me the output I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a non-greedy approach:

```
"\\\"(.*?)\\\""
```

A non-greedy cuts of a group from the moment it is possible. In this case from the moment a second double quote is found.

Or for instance match all characters appart from the quote:

```
"(\\\"[^\"]*)\\\")"
```

`[^list]` means all characters except the characters in the `list`

Furthermore, you can perhaps make it more readable by omitting double escaping:

```
"[\"]([^\"]*)[\"]"
```

Note furthermore that this doesn't work for recursive patterns: if the string to match is `"foo "inner" bar"`, it will match `"foo "` and not `"foo "inner" bar"`, but I guess that's the semantics one is looking for.

**EDIT:**

in case you allow escaped double quotes as well, you can use negative lookbehind:

```
"([\"][^\"]*(?<!\\\\)[\"])"
```

The `(?<!\\\\)` - unescaped `(?<!\)` - means that one character before, a backspace is not allowed.

A problem with this approach however, is that one can also specify a string:

```
"Foo\\"
```

This is used to specify the string `Foo\` (a real backspace).

A possible solution is to check if the lookbehind contains an odd number of consecutive backslashes, but that is not supported by Java, the solution is to make the inner loop of matching more complicated:

```
"([\"]([^\\\\\"]*([\\\\].)*)*[\"])"
```

Unescaped this regex is:

```
(["]([^\\"]*([\\].)*)*["])
  ^    ^       ^       ^
  |    |       |       \- tailing double quote
  |    |       \- if backslash, skip next character (for instance `\\`, `\"` or `\n`
  |    \- match all except double quotes and backslashes
  \-beginning double quote
```

See this [**jdoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/jW), it reads a raw string from the `stdin` and outputs the captured groups.

Comment: Hey, this worked great, but let's say for instance I have this: `"this is a \"string\""` then it will not work, do you know a work-around for this?

Comment: @bernhardkiv: have you tried the doodle? Note that you must double quote the string to introduce a hard backspace...

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really sure I was clear, I want it to match "this is a \"string\"" all in one group, the reason why I escaped the quotes is because I have this in plain-text in eclipse. Is that clear enough? :/

Comment: @bernhardkiv: that's only a matter of placing brackets. Updated both answer and jdoodle.

Comment: I tried the jdoodle, but that did not work either, it just outputted this: `input: this is a "string"
"string"`

Comment: @bernhardkiv: well what is the supposed output?

Comment: I expected one piece of output which is "this is a "string""

Comment: But if you parse the file, the real string reads: `"this is a \"string\""` or the escaped `\"this is a \\"string\\"\"`. If you enter this in the jdoodle, you get: "this is a \"string\"", so it skips backslash strings. In a file, the backslashes (are hard characters)

Comment: @bernhardkiv: simply try `say("this is a \"string\" do you understand?");` as standard input. This is how one would write a code file. The result is: `"this is a \"string\" do you understand?"` which is the string. Then you need to decode that string after matching.

Comment: I cannot get it to work today, and have to leave, how can I contact you for further help? As I would not like to post another question. *EDIT: Nevermind! got it to work, thank you SO SO much, you are a life saver :)*